# Can async/await pattern cause performance penalties on minor units of work?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

I'm looking for some guidance on the "workload threshold" between where async/await makes sense (e.g. to free up IO Completion Ports and avoid thread starvation) vs. unit of work being too simple/cheap to execute, so synchronous execution is a better choice.

In other words, could the use of async/await lead to degraded performance when used in conjunction with relatively fast/resource-inexpensive units of work, and simply executing the work synchronously would be the preferred approach?

Example (all in one method, all asynchronous with await):

- Save some minor update to DB
- Reading a very small file upload to a stream using `ReadAsStreamAsync`
- Copy read stream to file stream using `CopyToAsync`
- Flushing writer stream using `FlushAsync`

Comment: async are always slower as there is simply more code to run (unless there is no asynchronous portion altogether), so not clear what you are looking for...

Comment: @Alexei I'm looking for some guidance on the "workload threshold" between where async/await makes sense (e.g. to free up IO Completion Ports and avoid thread starvation) vs. unit of work being too simple/cheap to execute, so synchronous execution is a better choice.

Comment: I see. I'm afraid that you'll have to measure yourself and find what is acceptable for you. If it is not server application with heavy load than you may get away with synchronous version (obviously not on main UI thread for desktop case)... I personally think for server it is safer to go all the way async if possible - any particular resource tends to get busy for all threads at the same time and you quickly lose all request threads...

Comment: There is absolutely some threshold below which it's faster to do something synchronously, but I don't think any of these qualify (except FlushAsync on a MemoryStream).

Comment: The scheduler will probably make a big difference. If the notification happens on a thread pool thread and needs to be scheduled onto the main thread that incurs a significant overhead compared to directly handing it on the thread pool thread. See [`ConfigureAwait`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.configureawait.aspx)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, I think you are wrong about "async are always slower", infact if you notice, nothing is synchronous ever in computer science, your synchronous code anyway waits on locks for an async operation and it probably executes all logic that you would essentially to finish the operation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I recommend you approach this not from a timing standpoint, but from an I/O-vs-CPU standpoint.

CPU-bound methods are naturally synchronous; I/O-bound methods are naturally asynchronous.

I'm assuming that your environment is server-side, based on your example:

- *Save some minor update to DB*. Naturally asynchronous: network (or at least out-of-proc) communication, possibility of contention, disk I/O.
- *Reading a very small file upload to a stream using ReadAsStreamAsync*. Naturally asynchronous: network communication.
- *Copy read stream to file stream using CopyToAsync*. Naturally asynchronous: possibility of contention, disk I/O.
- *Flushing writer stream using FlushAsync*. Naturally asynchronous: possibility of contention, disk I/O.

All of these are naturally-asynchronous operations, so they should all be implemented asynchronously. CPUs are incredibly faster than memory, which is incredibly faster than network or disk I/O. Because of this, if you implement a naturally asynchronous method synchronously, you *will* block a thread. This isn't the end of the world, but the thread pool has to compensate if it's blocked for too long, and **the only time you're "saving" is the thread switch time, which will be orders of magnitude shorter than any network or disk I/O could possibly be**.

Another thing to consider is unpredictable latency, which usually happens due to resource contention. What if another process is writing to the db at the same time? What if there's a routing hiccup while the file is uploading, requiring retransmission of packets? What if the disk is defragmenting while you're trying to write the output file? Asynchronous operations have a tendency to be unpredictable like this, and `async` code ensures you won't be blocking a thread for much longer than you expected.

In conclusion: use synchronous code for synchronous (CPU-bound) work, and asynchronous code for asynchronous (I/O-bound) work.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you should know that just because you call a method asynchronously using the `await` keyword, that does not mean that the method cannot run synchronously. Or to be precise: such methods typically return either a `Task`, `Task<T>` or an `IAsyncOperation<TResult>` (in Windows Runtime), and that task may very well be completed when the method returns. In that case, the overhead is pretty small, because the executing thread will simply continue running.

As for the threshold itself, that depends on what you want to do and in which environment you run. Is this a UI app or a server app? Do you want to run asynchronously to free the UI, or rather to make better (i.e. more scalable) use of server threads?

In the case of the Windows Runtime API's, Microsoft used a threshold of 50 milliseconds, meaning that any method that could potentially take more than 50 milliseconds to execute, is offered only in an asynchronous form. The logic behind this is fairly simple: doing so would make it possible for the UI thread to execute long procedures, and never be blocked for more than 50 milliseconds. In other words, the UI thread could run other useful code, e.g. render a frame, 20 times per second or more.

Charles Petzold wrote [a good article about it on his blog](http://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2011/11/Asynchronous-Processing-in-Windows-8.html).

For the server scenario, it becomes useful to run asynchronously as soon as the work you can do by freeing a thread is more than the work it takes to free the thread. In my experience, that is the case for virtually all IO. There is of course the exception of something that looks like IO, but is really reading from or writing to a memory buffer, but in those cases the task returned by the method will complete synchronously.