# Suitable wall clock time threshold for when a method should be used async?

Tags: swift, multithreading, performance, asynchronous, execution-time

I believe this question to be programming language agnostic, but for reference, I am most interested in Swift.

When we perform a Pythagoras calculation inside a method, we know that for 32 or 64 bit `Int` this will be a fast operation.

```
func calculatePythagoras(sideX x: Int, sideY y: Int) -> Int {
    return sqrt(x*x+y*y)
}
```

We can call this method syncronously since we consider it to be fast enough.

Of course, it would be silly - assuming `Int` of max 64-bit size - to implement this in an asynchronous manner:

```
func calculatePythagorasAsync(sideX x: Int, sideY y: Int, done: (Int) -> Void) -> Void {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
        let sideZ = sqrt(x*x+y*y)
        DispatchQueue.main.async { 
            done(sideZ)
        }
    }
}
```

This is just overcomplicating the code since we can assume that disregarding of how old and slow the device we are running on, performing two multiplications and one square root of integers of max size 64 this will execute **fast enough.**

This is what I am interested in, what is **fast enough**?. Let's say that for the sake of simplicity we constrain this discussion to one specific device `D`. Let's say that the execute (wall clock time) for calculating Pythagoras on device `D` is 1 microsecond.

What do you think is a reasonable threshold for a method `M` should be changed to asynchronous? Imagine we would like to call this method `M` every time we display a table view (list view) cell (item), calling `M` on the main thread. And we would like to keep a smooth 60 fps when scrolling. 1 microsecond is surely fast enough. Of course, 100,000 microseconds (= 0.1 seconds) is not nearly fast enough. Probably 10,000 microseconds (= 0.01 s) is not fast enough either.

Is 1,000 microseconds (= 1 millisecond = 0.001 s) fast enough?

I hope you do not think this is a silly question, I am genuinely interested.

Is there any reference to some standard regarding this? Some best practice?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can async/await pattern cause performance penalties on minor units of work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19699566/can-async-await-pattern-cause-performance-penalties-on-minor-units-of-work)

Comment: TL;DR, around 50-100ms I marked my own question as a duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/a/19704132/1311272 that says 50ms, I found this on UX.stackexchange, saying 100 ms for UI thread block: https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/42688